# Dell Ubuntu 20.04 black screen on boot

Tags: dell

After installation of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS in a dual boot with Windows 10 on a Dell Inspiron 7577, after the GRUB screen, it gets stuck at the loader.

[image]

If I connect an external monitor with HDMI, the monitor works fine, but the loader still spins on the laptop's screen.

[image: image with external monitor]

Comment: Is the circle above "Ubuntu" rotating or static? What happens if you press `Esc` key here?

Comment: @codlord rotating, esc does nothing

Comment: @codlord Esc worked for me

Comment: I am facing the same issue, Please let me know the solution for this one?

Answer (score 1):

I have a slightly different setup (18.04), but the same problem, and this worked:

Delete `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`.

Source: https://superuser.com/questions/1369855/update-to-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-makes-my-laptop-display-not-accessible